# How to use curl command with parameters and executing the command from Python script(Python 2.6.6))

Tags: python, linux, curl

I am writing a python script to automate some works.

I need to execute **Curl** command from Python script and redirect the returned json output to a file so that i can parse the file using python script.

Also, I need to pass variables in the Curl command.

My curl command is something looks like

```
curl -k -u <$username:&password> -X GET "https://xxxxxx:0000/rest/$jobtype/$id"  > jsonOutput.json
```

FYI, I We are using Python 2.6.6 version

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Jee

Answer (score 0):

Better, if you use [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). It will be very easy to make HTTP requests using this module and also, you don't need to save output in different file. A lot of IO will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to call external commands from Python.

Try:

```
subprocess.Popen('curl -k -u <$username:&password> -X GET "https://xxxxxx/Users/$username/$folderName/$id"', shell=True,  stdout=open('outputfile.json'))
```

However, its better to write each part of the command in an array like this

```
subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-k', '-u', 'user:pass', '-X', '-GET', url], stdout=open('outputfile.json'))
```

Then there is no need to use `shell=True` which is safer if you are using any user generated input in that command. Providing a user access to a shell is not safe!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, Can i use python variable(input received from command line) in the curl command?

Comment: @Jee yes sure, see my second example, I pass the variable called `url` (it's not a string) in the argument list. Its value will be passed to the external command. You can take the input of `url` from any source you like.

Comment: In general, each space separated part of the external command should be a separate element in the array you pass to `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: I executed the script like you have mentioned. I could see the script executed, but there is no output in outputfile.json. How can we get the output to be displayed on terminal(stdout) instead of redirecting it to a file.

Comment: @Jee don't set the `stdout` parameter then. The output of running the command should be displayed on the terminal then. You should see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)for more information about this.